# Calling jasmine test in another file result in a timeout

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, protractor

I want to test my app for both logged in / guest users.

I found myself simulating login/logout many times, so I put the respective test code (including relevent calls to `it()` and `expect()`) in a separate page object file (`login.po.ts`)

My angular2 e2e test file looks like this:

```js
// ...

it('should navigate to /some-page', () =>
{
    // ...tests performed as guest user
});

it('should login', () =>
{
    // Login
    login.testLogin();
});

it('should perform tests as logged in user', () =>
{
    // ...tests performed as logged in user
});
```

### My problem is

Whenever I call login test routines, they get executed correctly. However, jasmine timeout, even though it shouldn't; it just wait for 5 seconds and then report the timeout!

login test function looks like this:

```js
this.page.navigateTo('/account/login').then(() =>
{
    const userName = 'some@user.com';
    const password = 'Pass123456!';

    this.page.sendKeys('input[name="username"]', userName, true);
    this.page.sendKeys('input[name="password"]', password, true);

    this.page.submit('form[name="form"]').then(() =>
    {
        expect(this.page.getElement('a#logout')).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

I'm new to jasmine, I'm not sure how to fix this, I've been trying to overcome this issue for days now, I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement should include the exact error message, which should make it easy for debugging. Please see that [there are a lot of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972402/protractor-jasmine-timeout-issue) for timeouts in Protractor.

If your error is due to your spec taking more time than Jasmine timeout than you can specify Jasmine to wait for more time using the `jasmineNodeOpts` in your `conf.js` file.

For example, you can set Jasmine spec to wait for more than specified time out by using this

```
     exports.config={
framework:'jasmine',
]
seleniumAddress:"http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
jasmineNodeOpts:{   
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 500000,
},
```

This is being talked in length in the link that I have attached above. Please read it for greater clarity.